# Trigger script when only certain sheets are activated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have several sheets that begin with "Agent Report" followed by the name, like this: "Agent Report - John", "Agent Report - Adam", etc. I have a script that reads the name of the agent from a specific cell and retrieves the data from another spreadsheet for that person. I want to trigger the script when a sheet that begins with "Agent Report" is activated, so that when I move between the sheets, the sheet data are updated for each person in "Agent Report" sheets. So far I have this:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  makeMenu();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sname = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if(sname.indexOf("Agent Report")>-1){
    master();
  }
}
```

Agent Report is not the first sheet, so the script correctly makes a custom menu (makeMenu) when I open the spreadsheet, but does not get triggered (master) when I switch to an "Agent Report" sheet. When I run the script manually from an "Agent Report" sheet, it runs fine.

My question is: Can I create a trigger that will run the script when I switch to a sheet with the name that begins with "Agent Report"? `onOpen()` doesn't seem to fit for that purpose.

If such a trigger is not possible, can there be a workaround - a loop that would go over every sheet, check the name and if it contains "Agent Report", run the script. Something like that:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var numberOfSheets = ss.getSheets().length;     
  for (var i = 0; i<=numberOfSheets; i ++) {
    if(SOMETHING HERE.indexOf("Agent Report")[i] > -1){
      master();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Issue:

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene):

> The `onOpen(e)` trigger runs automatically when a user opens a
> spreadsheet, document, presentation, or form that they have permission
> to edit.

The problem with this approach is that `onOpen` is executed **only** the time you **open** the spreadsheet file. Therefore, even if you switch between sheets or do any other operations, the script won't be executed, unless you refresh/open the spreadsheet file again. In other words, `onOpen` will only be executed for the sheet that you open the first time.

---

### Solution 1:

To execute a code when switching between different sheets you can use [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee):

```
  function onSelectionChange(e) {
    makeMenu();
    const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
      if (as.getName().indexOf("Agent Report")>-1){ 
        master();
      }
    }
```

I **don't** recommend you to choose this approach because **every time** you make a **selection change** in the script, the code will be executed.

---

### Solution 2 (recommended):

As you also proposed, to control when you want to execute the script I would advice you to use a **regular** function that iterates over all sheets and checks if the sheet name matches the criterion. Add also `onOpen` to execute `makeMenu()`:

```
function allSheets(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  
  sheets.forEach(sh=>{                 
  if(sh.getName().indexOf("Agent Report")>-1){
  master();
  }});
}


function onOpen() {
  makeMenu();
}
```

You can execute this regular function in many different ways:

1. script editor
2. create a custom menu and execute it from the spreadsheet file
3. create an icon button within your spreadsheet file
4. create a time-driven trigger to execute on a particular time

---

**Bonus information:**

In both approaches, you can replace

```
if(as.getName().indexOf("Agent Report")>-1)
```

with

```
if(as.getName().includes("Agent Report"))
```

which does exactly the same thing, but it is more eye-friendly.

---

### Related Issue:

As also pointed out by [Iamblichus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011/iamblichus), an `onSheetChange` trigger function has already been requested by the community and it is reported in the [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72140210). Go ahead and click on the star (★) button to the top left of the webpage to increase the chances of this feature to be implemented in the future.

Comment: There's a feature request related to this in Issue Tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72140210. Would you consider adding that to your answer?

Comment: @MikeB. `sh` is implicitly by the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function. Essentially, `sh` represents each element in the `sheets` array and therefore there is no need to define it. Please have a look at the documentation. You can achieve the same thing with a for loop, but `forEach` is more efficient in your scenario, since you don't need to define the length of the array and therefore have a cleaner approach.

Comment: * implicitly defined

Comment: Thank you, Marios and Lamblichus. I used Option 2 changing it to onOpen(e)
However, master() doesn't run because it retrieves the name of the agent from a cell in the "Agent Report" sheet. Before when I was working from within this sheet, I used it as getActiveSheet(), but now the active sheet is the first. How can I either make active sheet change to the next "Agent Report" sheet or to retrieve the name and run the code for each "Agent Report" sheet?
And, a newbie question: "sh" in " if(sh.getName()" is not defined, but I'm not getting an error. And, why sh "=>" the IF statement?

Comment: @MikeB. see my updated solution (solution 2). Essentially, use `onOpen` as a separate function (you don't need to execute it) . And execute only `allSheets()` when it is desired.

Comment: @Marios. If I use onOpen(){allSheets();}, master() script doesn't run correctly because it uses getActiveSheet() to get the value for the agent's name. Since the active sheet is the first, master() doesn't get to run on the "Agent Report" sheets where it needs to run. I need to somehow either change active sheet from the first to the second, to the third etc. OR to change the script not to use getActiveSheet, but get sheet that contains "Agent report" and cycle through all sheets, executing the script only on those. Perhaps this is a topic for a separate question.

Comment: @MikeB. Where exactly did I tell you to put `allSheets` **in** the `onOpen` function ? Please read again my answer (solution 2) which I clearly mention to save both functions in the script editor and manually execute only `allSheets` when needed. Please focus more on my answer.

Comment: @Marios. I know you didn't. I'm just trying to find a solution so that the script is triggered when I open the spreadsheet and runs only on certain sheets that contain "Agent Report" in the name. The final spreadsheet has to run automatically without my input. So, that's why I need some trigger for the script that would cycle through the sheets and work only on the "Agent Report" sheets. I guess time-driven trigger seems be the only option to periodically update those sheets, though I would prefer to have it run op open. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @MikeB. Please post a new question to clarify exactly what you need so other experts can also help you (including me ) :) sorry for the inconvenience but stack overflow does not allow follow up questions.

Answer (score -2):

The final solution was to use installable trigger (not a simple trigger, this is why the script did not run onOpen) with the following script:

```
function allSheets() {
  makeMenu();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sh=>{
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sh);     
    if (sh.getName().includes("Agent Report")) {
      master();
    }
  })
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheets[0]);
}
```

Thank you @Marios for all the helpful tips.